# Добавить новый массив js

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, как организовать то что находиться в комментариях else

```
if (gifts[0] == undefined)
{
    var id = 0;
    gifts[id]= new Array();

    gifts[id]['id'] = id;
    gifts[id]['type'] = type;

    console.log(gifts[id]['type']);
} else {
    // тут добавить ещё один массив с новыми значениями
    // id = самый последний в массиве
    // type = type
}
```

Comment: а id по порядку идут?

Comment: @zhenyab да

Answer (score 1):

//Где-то там вверху будет чтото вроде

```
var gifts = [];
```

//Наш код

```
gifts.push({
    id: gifts.length,
    type: type
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (gifts.length == 0) {
  var id = 0;
  gifts[id] = {
    'id': id,
    'type': type 
  };
} else {
  var id = gifts.length;
  gifts.push({
    'id': id,
    'type': type 
  });   
}
```

Comment: @Konstantin Gusev

Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'push'